# Deploying .Net Applications from Jenkins to IIS(Full Automation)

Tags: .net, jenkins, iis, automation, devops

I have a short experience with Jenkins and Jenkinsfiles and it was on linux servers.
Now I have .Net apps and windows servers that use IIS and I'm totally new to both of them
I want to find a way to deploy .NET apps to iis via Jenkins. But I could not find a way that i would understand or it's not a fully automated process(Like i have to create a site in iis manually )
or it.

PS: My Jenkins Master is on Linux and The agents on Windows...

Comment: Everything on IIS can be automated in PowerShell, so time to study and utilize that. https://octopus.com/blog/iis-powershell

Comment: You can use PowerShell scripts for automating Web Deploy setup. more information you can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/powershell-scripts-for-automating-web-deploy-setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/powershell-scripts-for-automating-web-deploy-setup).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have the same configuration. I had to implement batch commands and powershell scripts in the pipeline script which is Groovy.  Now I think to change the batch commands also to powershell.